# Gradle don't build on :app:mergeDebugResources failure

Tags: android, gradle, build, heap-memory

I have recently started a new Android App and I'm getting this extremely annoying error that is avoiding me to build the project.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23-1' (Expected 'C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23')
Already observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23' in 'C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23-1'
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2400Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
radle.properties file.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
<em>org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m</em>
<a href="http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html">Read Gradle's configuration guide</a><br><a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html">Read about Java's heap size</a>
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 9.513 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

The issue seems to be in this parte of the build:

```
:app:mergeDebugResources
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I have just started this app. It has only two activities and 4 displays. Almost no resources despite a few strings and images. Why would I face problems with heap memory? Could it be because I have 2 android studio projects open at the same time?

I'm using: 
-Gradle version 2.10
-Android Plugin Version 2.1.2

I have already ran a "clean project", "rebuild project", "sync project with gradle files". It didn't help.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Possibly.  Or your project is just really big.  Increase your heap size in the config file, this is a case where throwing memory at it is the right solution.

Comment: Hello @GabeSechan. I don't think the project is that big. I just started it and it has only two activities. I don't think it could be the project size...

Comment: Agrees, it doesn't sound like it, unless you just had a tiny java heap to begin with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is issue with your resources.
Check out the size of images you used in **drawable**. 
Decrease the size and resolution of images and then rebuild the project.

Comment: Man, you are the best! That was the reason. I got a svg file I converted to xml and I didn't realize it had something like 20000dp of width and also a huge height. I resized it to a normal size and it builds normally now! Thanks!